# Order of Recursion (SQL Server CTE)

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, with-statement

I can achieve recursion by using SQL Server's With command (CTE).

```
WITH MyCTE(ParentID,ID,Name,Level)
AS
(
SELECT ManagerID AS ParentID, UserID AS ID, UserName AS Name, 0 AS Level 
FROM USERS U       
WHERE U.ManagerID IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT U.ManagerID AS ParentID, U.UserID AS ID, U.UserName AS Name, H.Level+1 AS Level
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN MyCTE H ON H.ID = U.ManagerID
)

SELECT ParentID,ID FROM MyCTE
```

returns

```
ParentID    ID
NULL        1
1           2
1           3
2           4
```

What I want to achieve is to reverse this result set. Namely,reversing the root node and the deepest child node as,

```
ParentID    ID
NULL        4
4           2
2           1
3           1
```

Couldn't figure out how to programmatically implement this (preferably by using CTE), like by using a parameter to determine the recursion order etc. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit :

Modified this a bit inserting my first CTE's results into a temp table, then using another recursion I reverse the order as (I know "WHERE T.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tmp)" wont work in a real situation, I also gotta determine the deepest node with the "Level" column, just tried to simplify this for this example),

```
 INSERT INTO @tmp
 SELECT ParentID,ID,Level FROM MyCTE
 WITH MyCTE2(ParentID,ID,Level)
 AS
 (
 SELECT NULL AS ParentID, ID AS ID, 0 AS Level FROM @tmp T 
 WHERE T.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tmp)

 UNION ALL

 SELECT R2.ID AS ParentID, T.ParentID AS ID, R2.Level+1 FROM @tmp T
 INNER JOIN MyCTE2 R2 ON R2.ID = T.ID
 WHERE T.ParentID IS NOT NULL
 )
```

Original Results (removed the 1,3 pair)

```
ParentID   ID   Level
  NULL      1     0
    1       2     1
    2       4     2
```

Reversed results,

```
ParentID   ID   Level
  NULL      4     0
    4       2     1
    2       1     2
```

Edit 2:

I did something like this,

```
SELECT TTT.ParentID,TTT.ID,TTT.Level FROM
(
SELECT ParentID,ID,Level FROM MyCTE2
UNION ALL
SELECT TT.ID AS ParentID,TT.ParentID AS ID,(SELECT Level+1 FROM @tmp WHERE ID=TT.ID) 
AS  Level  FROM
(
SELECT ID FROM @tmp
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM MyCTE2
)T INNER JOIN @tmp TT ON TT.ID = T.ID
)TTT
ORDER BY TTT.Level
```

gives,

```
ParentID    ID  Level
NULL        4   0
4           2   1
2           1   2
3           1   2
```

This may contain errors, im not sure yet, just wanted to show to make sure that pair (3,1) is whther correct with level 2 ? Been thinking on this for quite a while now, I might make some silly mistakes.

Comment: @MartinSmith that wont work read the post carefully.

Comment: @MartinSmith recreate the hierarchy in reverse order.

Comment: You need to build the hierarchy first, so basically add another CTE after your existing CTE to go backwards.  There's no way to know how many levels deep something is without building the  tree first.

Comment: so simply make another recursion taking the deepest node as the root node right?

Comment: Perhaps including the sample data that provides oyur sample results would assist those trying to help you.

Comment: @OzanYukruk - correct.  The problem is that you don't know there are 4 levels built off your parent til you recurse through the whole tree.

Comment: Could be done - but the solution isn't pretty.  Dare I say...

Comment: Then again when are hierarchies pretty...I'd look into Joe Celko's stuff.  He loved doing these types of puzzles.

Comment: reversing the resultset of a recursion, isnt my question clear?

Comment: Your result is not clear. How can `ParentID` for `ID=4` be `2` in one case and `null` in the other?

Comment: @OzanYukruk - its recursion what do you expect.  its recursion what do you expect.  its recursion what do you expect.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Because in the end 4->2 and 2->1 and 1->Null.

Comment: Thats not clear from my side aswell, perhaps creating a tree per deepest child node would suffice.

Comment: @OzanYukruk - Get a clear definition of what they want.  This question is difficult to think about, let alone answer it.  And answer it in such a way that doesn't make sense in the end.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying to achieve that Martin, i actually did, however I'm missing the values from original recursion that's not the parent of any node. (ID=3 at my example)

Comment: @JonH - Ah. Should there not be a `(null, 3)` in there as well since there is a `(3, 1)` ?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I would say it was not added but should be yes.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I've missed that one. Posting my current results (And removing the (3,1) pair for a clear explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample data

```
declare @T table
(
  ParentID int,
  ID int
)

insert into @T values
(NULL,        1),
(1   ,        2),
(1   ,        3),
(2   ,        4)
```

Recursion from root:

```
;with C as
(
  select ParentID, ID
  from @T
  where ParentID is null
  union all
  select T.ParentID, T.ID
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ParentID = C.ID
)
select *
from C
```

Result

```
ParentID    ID
----------- -----------
NULL        1
1           2
1           3
2           4
```

Recursion from leafs:

```
;with C as
(
  select null as PParentID, ID, ParentID
  from @T
  where ID not in (select ParentID 
                   from @T 
                   where ParentID is not null)
  union all
  select C.ID, T.ID, T.ParentID 
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ParentID 
)
select distinct
       PParentID as ParentID,
       ID
from C
```

Result:

```
ParentID    ID
----------- -----------
NULL        3
NULL        4
4           2
2           1
3           1
```

If you have many branches you will have duplicate rows as merge together. Using `distinct` takes care of that.

To get the levels correct you need to first calculate the level from top down. Store that in a table variable (or temp table) and then use that as the source for leaf->root recursion.

```
-- Primary key and unique is in there to get the indexes used in the recursion  
declare @T2 table
(
  ParentID int,
  ID int,
  Level int,
  primary key (ID),
  unique(ParentID, ID)
)

;with C as
(
  select ParentID, ID, 0 as Level
  from @T
  where ParentID is null
  union all
  select T.ParentID, T.ID, Level + 1
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ParentID = C.ID
)
insert into @T2
select ParentID, ID, Level
from C

;with C as
(
  select null as PParentID, ID, ParentID, Level
  from @T2
  where ID not in (select ParentID 
                   from @T2 
                   where ParentID is not null)
  union all
  select C.ID, T.ID, T.ParentID, T.Level
  from @T2 as T
    inner join C
      on T.ID = C.ParentID 
)
select distinct
       PParentID as ParentID,
       ID,
       max(Level) over() - Level as level
from C
```

Result:

```
ParentID    ID          level
----------- ----------- -----------
NULL        3           1
NULL        4           0
2           1           2
3           1           2
4           2           1
```

It is possible but a really bad idea to replace @T2 with a multi CTE query. It will kill performance because to first CTE will be rebuilt for each recursion. At least that is my guess of what is happening but believe me it is not fast.

Comment: Yeah pretty much the same logic as I've updated my post. At first, I was trying to handle this with a single CTE and using a parameter to determine the order of recursion. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @OzanYukruk - This **is** with a single CTE. The first is from root and down (ignore it). The second finds the nodes that is not parents and walks up.

Comment: Yeah, but in your example you are using a temp table as a reference. However in my case, my reference table is a resultset obtained with a CTE. (Using more then 1 "UNION ALL" in my real code, attaching like 10 tables with a parent-child hierarchy) So i gotta send another parameter to determine if it demands the reversed resultset aswell.

Comment: @OzanYukruk Yes. The temp table is instead of whatever source of information you have.

Comment: Yeah, In my case thats my first CTE :).

Comment: @JonH - Thanks. With a little help... :)

Comment: Mikael, could you please add "Level" aswell? There's an error if im not wrong. Reversed resultset contains (2,1)Level-2 and (3,1)Level-1. Namely, node1 is both in Level1 and Level2

Comment: @OzanYukruk - Yes that is what happens. I guess you want the leaf node `(null, 3)` to start on level `1` instead of `0` right? I currently have no idea how to do that. Will update answer if I figure it out.

Comment: @OzanYukruk - Added a version with levels. Had to use a table variable as in between thing. Don't replace that variable with a CTE it will kill performance for you.

Comment: I just edited my initial post with a possible answer aswell, could you check that please? I'm also checking yours right now.